# Flutter Provider Issue - Changes are not reflecting

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Can anyone please let me know why this code is not working? I have one data model file, One file for page where i have a search text and listview to display the names and main file. If i enter something on the search bar, names should be filtered. Please check the code and let me know what i have done wrong.

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import './class.dart';`enter code here`

class NameList with ChangeNotifier {
  List<NameDetails> names = [
    NameDetails('2', 'Mahesh'),
    NameDetails('1', 'Ganesh'),
    NameDetails('3', 'Suresh'),
    NameDetails('4', 'Girish'),
  ];

  List<NameDetails> get getNames {
    return names;
  }

  void filterNames(String fil) {
    List<NameDetails> names1;
    names1 = names.where((n) => n.name.contains(fil));
    names=names1;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:practice/class.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import './data.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  NameList namesList;
  String filterValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final namesList = Provider.of<NameList>(context);
    List<NameDetails> names = namesList.names;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: TextField(
            onChanged: (text) {
              namesList.filterNames(text);
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Text('${names[index].name}'),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: names.length,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './mainScreen.dart';
import './data.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => NameList(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Test',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MainScreen(),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you permanently change `names` and never reset it. So once all names are cleared, you have no way to get them back – hence it may appear that your UI is not refreshing

Comment: @RemiRousselet, then how should i write my filterNames function? Please suggest..

Comment: Instead make the function return a clone of the list, which contains the filtered elements.

Comment: @RemiRousselet If i return the clone, notifyListeners won't be triggered.

Comment: You wouldn't need `notifyListeners` anymore. Store the filter as part of the State of your widget, and call `setState` when the filter changes

Comment: @RemiRousselet, i can make it work using setstate. But, i am trying to use providers (New to flutter and learning providers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can put filter function in `getNames` and use `List<NameDetails> names = namesList.getNames;` 
Step 2: `filterNames` function only update _searchString and do `notifyListeners()`

code snippet

```
class NameList with ChangeNotifier {
  List<NameDetails> names = ...

  String _searchString = "";

  UnmodifiableListView<NameDetails> get getNames => _searchString.isEmpty
      ? UnmodifiableListView(names)
      : UnmodifiableListView(
          names.where((n) => n.name.contains(_searchString)));

  void filterNames(String fil) {
    _searchString = fil;
    print(_searchString);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

...
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final namesList = Provider.of<NameList>(context);
    List<NameDetails> names = namesList.getNames;
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'dart:collection';

class NameDetails {
  String id;
  String name;

  NameDetails(this.id, this.name);
}

class NameList with ChangeNotifier {
  List<NameDetails> names = [
    NameDetails('2', 'Mahesh'),
    NameDetails('1', 'Ganesh'),
    NameDetails('3', 'Suresh'),
    NameDetails('4', 'Girish'),
  ];

  String _searchString = "";

  UnmodifiableListView<NameDetails> get getNames => _searchString.isEmpty
      ? UnmodifiableListView(names)
      : UnmodifiableListView(
          names.where((n) => n.name.contains(_searchString)));

  void filterNames(String fil) {
    _searchString = fil;
    print(_searchString);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => NameList(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Test',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MainScreen(),
        ));
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  NameList namesList;
  String filterValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final namesList = Provider.of<NameList>(context);
    List<NameDetails> names = namesList.getNames;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: TextField(
            onChanged: (text) {
              namesList.filterNames(text);
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Text('${names[index].name}'),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: names.length,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```